# 'ASIHTTPRequest' is not responding to setPostValue, need to pass email id as parameter

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

i am new to iOS development , recently i'm working with 'ASIHTTPRequest' library. i have downloaded it's example from    [Here](https://codeload.github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/legacy.tar.gz/master). it's working fine. I need to send a parameter to my web service as 'email' and also authentication needed.

i tried following 
`[request setPostValue:@"abcd@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"];` based on  [this Reference](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

but it's give me warning that `Instance method -setPostValue:forKey() not found`. How can i pass email id as parameter to web service? For your reference i use web service to reset password when user forgot it.

EDIT :

Now , i need to convert following code into `ASIFormDataRequest` from `ASIHTTPRequest` with email id parameter and authentication. can you help me now ?
`

```
[self setRequest:[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abc.foo.com/api/forgot_password/"]]];
    [request setUseKeychainPersistence:[useKeychain isOn]];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setShouldPresentAuthenticationDialog:[useBuiltInDialog isOn]];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(topSecretFetchComplete:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(topSecretFetchFailed:)];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

`

Comment: sounds like a typo in your source code. check the line were the warning appears. you might wrote [request setPostValue:@"..." forjey:@"..."]; ;)

Comment: it's ok in code. i just made mistake when typing question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [`ASIHTTPRequest`](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/master/Classes/ASIHTTPRequest.h) doesn't include a `-setPostValue:forKey:` method. [`ASIFormDataRequest`](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/master/Classes/ASIFormDataRequest.h), on the other hand, does.

It sounds like you're using a pointer of type `ASIHTTPRequest*` to send a message to an instance of `ASIFormDataRequest`. That's okay if the pointer really points to a form data request, ASIFormDataRequest being a subclass of ASIHTTPRequest, but if you're sure enough about the type of the object that you can send it a message specific to it's type, you also know enough to either use the more specific type in the first place or use a type cast to let the compiler know that it doesn't need to complain.

Comment: You are right, can help me little more, i have edited my question. can you suggest me how can i convert my code ? Thank you so much for your feedback.

Comment: I'd guess you can simply replace `ASIHTTPRequest` with `ASIFormDataRequest` and add calls like `[request setPostValue:email forKey:@"email"];`, etc.